# Yii2 CheckboxList doesn't give back value

Tags: php, forms, yii2, checkboxlist

I try to make a checkboxlist field where the user select numbers and the selected values are saved to the database .

I'm strugling with this problem a few day and i'm alread tryed everything

So here is my code -its already mixed with codes from other posts-
Oh and the checkboxlist doesn't give back the value just an empty array
Form:

```
    <?php $list = ["1" => '1', "2" => '2', "3" => '3', "4" => '4'];?>

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
    <?= $form->field($jegyModel, 'chairline') ?>
    <?= $form->field($jegyModel, 'name') ?>
    <?= $form->field($jegyModel, 'tnumber') ?>
    <?= $form->field($jegyModel, 'email') ?>
    <?= $form->field($takModel, 'quantArray')->checkboxList($list,['inline'=>true])?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>



<?=print_r($takModel->quantArray); give back empty array

?>
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        'movie',
        'startday',
        'start',
        'end',
        [
            'value' => $model->ticketprice,
            'label' => 'Ticketprice',
        ],
    ],
]) ?>
```

And i have a class based on a post what i found here

```
<?php
namespace app\models;
class TakMolForm extends Sjegyek
{
    private $_quantArray;

    public function getQuantArray()
    {
        if($this->_quantArray == null)
        {
            $this->_quantArray = explode(',', $this->chairnumber);
        }
        return $this->_quantArray;
    }

    public function setQuantArray($value)
    {
        $this->_quantArray = $value;
    }


    public function rules()
    {
        return array_merge(parent::rules(), [
            [['quantArray'], 'safe'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

controller

```
 public function actionFilm($id)
    {
        $jegyModel = new Sjegyek();
        $takModel = new TakMolForm();



        if ($jegyModel->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $jegyModel->chairnumber = implode(',', $takModel->quantArray);
            $jegyModel->movieid=$id;
            if($jegyModel->save()) {
                return $this->render('test', [
                    'model' => $this->findModel($id),
                    'jegyModel' => $jegyModel,
                    'takModel' => $takModel,
                ]);

            } else {
                return $this->render('film', [
                    'model' => $this->findModel($id),
                    'jegyModel' => $jegyModel,
                    'takModel' => $takModel,

                ]);

            }

        }
        return $this->render('film', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
            'jegyModel' => $jegyModel,
            'takModel' => $takModel,
        ]);

    }
```

and model for Sjegyek

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "jegyek".
 *
 * @property string $chairnumber
 * @property string $chairline
 * @property string $name
 * @property string $tnumber
 * @property string $email
 * @property int $movieid
 */
class Sjegyek extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'jegyek';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {

        return [
            [['chairnumber', 'chairline', 'name', 'tnumber', 'email', 'movieid'], 'required'],
            [['movieid'], 'integer'],
            [['chairnumber', 'name', 'email'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['chairline'], 'string', 'max' => 4],
            [['tnumber'], 'string', 'max' => 250],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'chairnumber' => 'Chairnumber',
            'chairline' => 'Chairline',
            'name' => 'Name',
            'tnumber' => 'Tnumber',
            'email' => 'Email',
            'movieid' => 'Movieid',
        ];
    }
}
```

This post is my last hope because im already try everything what i saw here .

Comment: You should use at least international language to name your db table and columns so we can understand what is going on.

Comment: You never called `$takModel->load()`, so obviously it is always empty.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ichsanmust\grid for checklist columns

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (Yii::$app->request->post()) {
      $jegyModel->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
      $takModel->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
    
      rest of your code
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.